# can't get rid of vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

here is the live link http://mrgsp.md:8080/icms/account/signin

I get a scrollbar and I don't understand why and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Do you need html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

Comment: @DanS I think I needed this before, but now I don't see why

Comment: for some reason your `body` tag doesn't start at the top of the browser's viewport. The `html` element does in fact start at the top so it seems like the `html` element has a `top-padding`, but I've been looking through your code but have not been able to find the reason. At least you know where to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try removing `html {height: 100%}`

Comment: Yep, this is pretty much meaningless anyway.

Comment: Btw, this is happening because #loginbox and body margins are collapsing, hence the virtual "margin-top: 200px" applied to the body. 100% + margin = scrollbar. You'd better use an absolute position on your login box to achieve your vertical centering.

Comment: @Capsule anyway thnx, I changed to position relative and set top:200 and it's ok, turns out I actually do need height:100% for html

Comment: @Omu Or you can use `body {height: auto; padding-top: 200px}` and remove the `margin-top` from `#loginbox` (I just personaly use `position: relative` as the last possible option)

Comment: @Elwhis of course body margin is 0. This virtual margin is the result of the collapse. See http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing